How to identify who added users on a moodle course manually
we are using Moodle 4.0 and i cant find who added users on a course manually, is there a way to figure out who added them?
i tried looking up the logs but couldn't find anything, I am a site admin with all rights. thinking of SQL query or a plug in if there is another way would appreciate the help

Logs method:
Under: Site administration > Reports > Logs
The "Event name" will be "User enrolled in course".
The "User full name" column displays the user that enrolled someone.
The "Affected user" displays the enrolled user.
Both of those users are presented as links, so you can view their user details.
The "Description" column will include the user ID's of both users, the course ID, and the enrollment method.

Database method:
Assuming that you have database access, you could run something like:
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        enroller.firstname, ' ', enroller.lastname
    ) "Enroller",
    enroller.username "Enroller username",
    c.fullname "Course",
    CONCAT(
        enrollee.firstname, ' ', enrollee.lastname
    ) "Enrollee",
    enrollee.username "Enrollee username",
    FROM_UNIXTIME(ue.timecreated, '%Y-%m-%d') "Enrollment created"
FROM
    mdl_user_enrolments ue
    JOIN mdl_user enroller ON ue.modifierid = enroller.id
    JOIN mdl_user enrollee ON ue.userid = enrollee.id
    JOIN mdl_enrol e ON ue.enrolid = e.id
    JOIN mdl_course c ON e.courseid = c.id
WHERE
    e.enrol = 'manual'
ORDER BY
    ue.timecreated DESC;

Disclaimer for anyone reading this:
Please don't run SQL queries that someone else wrote against your database unless you completely understand them.
